# A simple problem of probability

Tags: probability

What's the probability to draw a single ace from a 52-card deck when you have two turns?

Comment: The probability of getting an ace on the first draw is 4/52 and not getting a 4 on the second draw is 48/51 assuming no replacement. So 2x(4x48)/(52 x51) is the result because it is the same probability to not get an ace on the first and get one on the second. These two probabilities add together because the two events are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't understand why is "and not getting a 4 on the second draw is 48/51 assume no replacement", why isn't 47/51? Because you remove one card. Could you explain me that and what you mean with "assuming no replacement"

Comment: It is because at that point you still have 48 cards that are not aces.

Comment: Alright! Finally I got it, thanks for your explanation

Comment: Well, my answer was ((4/52)*(48/51))+((48/52)*(4/51)), it was more intuitive for me, but it's the same in the result, using algebra we can get your result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment is my answer. However, if you sample with replacement it would be $2\times(4\times 48)/52^2$. This is because on the second draw you would still have all 52 cards in the deck.

Comment: Your answer is right, because I never said that there is no replacement.